# java.sql.SqlException: no data found while inserting the data into table

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to inserting the data into the table using ms access 2007 but getting the exception  "java.sql.SqlException: no data found"
My data souce name is employee

```
            import java.sql.*;

             class AccessDatabase
              {
                    public static void main(String[] args) 
                   {
                     try 
                         {
                   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:employee");
                   Statement st = con.createStatement();


                  String name = "roseindia";
                  String address = "delhi";
                  int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into user(name,address) values
                  ('" +  name + "','" + address + "')");
                  System.out.println("Row is added");

                        } 
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {
                     System.out.println(e);
                   }
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have a database created. Following code should work:

```
import java.sql.*;
class ExecuteSqlQuery {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  String str = "CREATE TABLE user(id INTEGER, " + "name VARCHAR(25), address VARCHAR(100), primary key(id))";
  st.executeUpdate(str);
  System.out.println("Table is created into the database.");
  st.executeUpdate("insert into user(id,name,address) values(1111,'roseindia','Rohini,Delhi')");
  System.out.println("Row is inserted.");
   st.close();
  con.close();
  } 
   catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
  }
  }
}
```